# Redirect from a Chrome Extension Popup

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How do I make it that when I click my extension button in the upper right, it redirects me to another page?
My manifest looks a little something like this.

```
{
  // Extension Info
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Extension",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Text",

  // Action
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon_64.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.htm"
   },

  // Other decorative stuff
  "icons": {
      "128": "icon_128.png",
      "64": "icon_64.png",
      "16": "icon_16.png"
   }
}
```

And popup looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.open("http://website.com",'_blank');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Redirecting...</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any Ideas?
Thanks!
-SensiAking1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In background script, implement an onclick handler for browserAction button as follows.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.update({ url: "http://website.com" });
});
```

Comment: This is actually a correct alternative solution, but something else needs to be said, since there is no background script in the reference code yet, and it won't work when a popup is defined.

Comment: Xan: I actually had a background script `"background": "bgredirect.htm",`, but thought it was irrelevant so didn't include it. My bad. So solution was to make the JS not inline and to put it in a seperate JS file. Thanks!

Comment: if this answer worked for you, please accept the answer